# Game of Life class

Tags: c++, beginner, game-of-life

I'm a beginner in C++, and I'd like you to review the class I wrote for the Game Of Life.

**GameOfLife.h**

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class GameOfLife{

    public:
        GameOfLife(void);
        GameOfLife(const unsigned &, const unsigned &);
        ~GameOfLife(void);
        void display(void);
        void swapCell(const unsigned &,const unsigned &);
        void updateField();

    private:
        unsigned Xmax, Ymax;
        unsigned XSize, YSize;
        vector< vector<unsigned> > field;
        unsigned newValCell(const unsigned &, const unsigned &);
};
```

**GameOfLife.cpp**

```
#include "GameOfLife.h"

GameOfLife::GameOfLife(void) {
    Xmax = 10;
    Ymax = 10;
    XSize = Xmax + 2;
    YSize = Ymax + 2;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i != XSize; i++)
    {
        vector<unsigned> inter;
        for (unsigned j = 0; j != YSize; j++)
        {
            inter.push_back(0);
        }
        field.push_back(inter);
    }
}

GameOfLife::GameOfLife(const unsigned &x, const unsigned &y) {
    Xmax = x;
    Ymax = y;
    XSize = Xmax + 2;
    YSize = Ymax + 2;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i != XSize; i++)
    {
        vector<unsigned> inter;
        for (unsigned j = 0; j != YSize; j++)
        {
            inter.push_back(0);
        }
        field.push_back(inter);
    }
}

GameOfLife::~GameOfLife(void)
{
    return;
}

void GameOfLife::swapCell(const unsigned &x, const unsigned &y)
{
    field[x][y] = !field[x][y];
    return;
}

// return the new value of a cell depending on the surrounding values
unsigned GameOfLife::newValCell(const unsigned &x, const unsigned &y)
{
    unsigned stok;
    stok = field[x-1][y-1]
         + field[x-1][y]
         + field[x-1][y+1]
         + field[x][y-1]
         + field[x][y+1]
         + field[x+1][y-1]
         + field[x+1][y]
         + field[x+1][y+1];

    switch(stok)
    {
        case 3: return 1;
        case 2: return field[x][y];
        default: return 0;
    }
}

void GameOfLife::updateField(void)
{
    vector< vector<unsigned> > stockField = field;
    for (unsigned i = 1; i != Xmax + 1; i++)
    {
        for (unsigned j = 1; j != Ymax + 1; j++)
        {
            stockField[i][j] = newValCell(i,j);
        }
    }
    field = stockField;
    return;
}

void GameOfLife::display(void)
{
    for (int i = 1; i != Xmax + 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j != Ymax + 1; j++)
        {
            cout << field[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    return;
}
```

**`main()`**

```
#include "GameOfLife.h"

int main()
{
    GameOfLife a = GameOfLife(7,7);
    a.swapCell(1,5);
    a.swapCell(2,5);
    a.swapCell(3,5);
    a.swapCell(3,6);
    a.swapCell(2,7);
    a.display();
    cout << "-------\n";
    a.updateField();
    a.display();
    cout << "-------\n";
    a.updateField();
    a.display();
    cout << "-------\n";
    a.updateField();
    a.display();
    cout << "-------\n";
    a.updateField();
    a.display();
    cout << "-------\n";
    a.updateField();
    a.display();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't put `void` in the `( )` parameter list if the function takes 0 arguments, that's just useless boilerplate. Also, keeping the parameter names in function prototypes helps documenting the code.

Comment: `GameOfLife::GameOfLife(void) {` is really the same as `GameOfLife(10,10);`. Avoid copy-pasted code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use unsigned as your data storage you should instead use bool, `std::vector<bool>` is specialized to use a bit vector for more efficient storage.

Initialization of the field can happen in just 2 calls:

```
vector<bool> inter = vector<bool>(YSize, false);
field = vector<bool>(XSize, inter);
```

Speaking of the field, consider flattening the field so the field has size `YSize*XSize` and you index into it with `y*XSize+x` (which you can put in a helper method).

`newValCell` will happily go out of bounds and not notify you about it.

The for loops in `updateField` and `display` are 1-based while they should be 0-based (leads to an overflow).

`swapCell` is not well named, `toggleCell` or `invertCell` would be better, a explicit `setCell` and `unsetCell` wouldn't go amiss either.

You should allow the program to query the field state using a `getCell` method. So its not bound to a command line program.

Comment: the for loops goes from 1 to X/Ymax because the borders of the field are set to a constant value 0 and are never updated neither displayed. (or i misinterpret your comment?).

Comment: @user59330 then why +1 instead of -1 when adjusting the loop condition?

Comment: not sure but i think you confound Xmax (calculated field length) and XSize (array length).

Comment: @user59330 add that to the list, keeping the bounds twice, you only need it once

Comment: thx for your comments :)

Comment: `std::vector<bool>` may be designed to more compact but it is also much less efficient at access and has some freaky characteristics that are unlike all the other container types; So it becomes hard to use. `std::vector<char>` may be a better choice or if you must have bit sized compression then `boost::dynamic_bitset` may be a better choice.

Comment: [It is considered a mistake of the std](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8399470/14065)

Answer (score 7):

Here are some things that may help you improve your code:

### Don't abuse `using namespace std`

Putting `using namespace std` at the top of every program is [a bad habit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) that you'd do well to avoid.  It is particularly bad to put it into a header file, so please don't do that.

### Eliminate unused variables

The `XSize` and `YSize` variables are only used once in the constructor and can easily be eliminated.

### Prefer modern initializers for constructors

The constructors can be collapsed to a single one with default values and a parameter intialization style.  The declaration can have the default 10 x 10 size:

```
GameOfLife(const unsigned &x=10, const unsigned &=10);
```

The implementation can be much simplified by using `std::vector` constructors that take a `count`, `value` pair:

```
GameOfLife::GameOfLife(const unsigned &x, const unsigned &y) :
    Xmax(x), Ymax(y), field(Xmax+2, vector<bool>(Ymax+2, 0))
{
}
```

### Consider using `bool` instead of `int` for `field`

On my machine, the current code allocates a total of 3276 bytes, but that is reduced to 2600 if the type of `field` values is changed from `int` to `bool`.

### Reconsider function and field names

The name `swapCell` would probably be better named `toggleCell` because it's not really swapping with anything in the sense of [`std::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap).  Also, the naming of `Xmax` and `XSize` with lowercase 'm' and uppercase 'S' respectively seems a little inconsistent.

### Let the compiler create default destructor

The compiler will create a destructor by default which is essentially identical to what you've got, so you can simply omit both the declaraton and implementation from your code.

### Omit `return 0`

When a C++ program reaches the end of `main` the compiler will automatically generate code to return 0, so there is no reason to put `return 0;` explicitly at the end of `main`.  Similarly, there's no good reason to put `return;` at the end of a `void` function.

### Be careful with signed and unsigned

In the current `display` routine, the loop integers `i` and `j` are both signed `int` values, but they're being compared with `unsigned` quantities `Xmax` and `Ymax`.  Better would be to declare them all as `unsigned` or perhaps `size_t`.

### Use const where practical

The current `display()` routine does not (and should not) modify the underlying object, and so it should be declared `const`:

```
    void display(void) const;
```

Less obviously, perhaps, the `newValCell()` helper function should also be `const`.

### Use an `ostream &operator<<` instead of `display`

The current code has `void GameOfLife::display(void)` but what would make more sense and be more general purpose would be to overload an `ostream operator<<` instead.  The body of the existing `display` routine would only need small modifications:

```
friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const GameOfLife &game)
{
    for (unsigned i = 1; i != game.Xmax + 1; i++)
    {
        for (unsigned j = 1; j != game.Ymax + 1; j++)
        {
            out << game.field[i][j] << " ";
        }
        out << "\n";
    }
    return out;
}
```

Then the main routine could use this:

```
cout << a << "-------\n";
```

instead of this:

```
a.display();
cout << "-------\n";
```

### Reconsider the interface

Each call to `updateField` is something of an increment, so one possibility would be to declare it as an increment operator:

```
GameOfLife &operator++() { updateField(); return *this; }
```

If you did so and used the previous suggestion, the last part of the code for `main` could look like this:

```
cout << a << "-------\n";
for (int i=0; i < 5; ++i) 
{
    cout << ++a << "-------\n";
}
```

Comment: thx for your comments! how do you monitor the memory use?

Comment: I use [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) for that.  Very handy tool!

Comment: Input parameters that are basic types (`int`, `float`, `bool` etc) [should be passed by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/898789/is-there-any-specific-case-where-pass-by-value-is-preferred-over-pass-by-const-re). I didn't know the standard mandated a default `return 0` in `main()`, but I would still like to see explicit returns :)

Comment: `Omit return 0` - I read it more then once that it is actually a good style to always do that in main (unless you want to return something else ofc).

Comment: @EmilyL. good point about passing by value -- I neglected to mention that.